Impossible to solve Cloudflare Captcha due to timeouts
For the past 15 minutes I've been trying to solve a captcha that keeps refreshing to the same page and the reason, because it's set to timeout in 500ms on a line that has 1 second latency.
It keeps terminating the connection with NS_BINDING_ABORTED and retries to initiate another POST to figure out that I'm human and this keeps happening in an endless loop for over 700 times, just to look at a single answer.


can you tell me which route your script is posting against and also if possible give me the RayID response header to one of the captchas?

here you go 8d418d717af88ffe

And BTW, I have to do this for every subdomain even images

There was an issue on Cloudflare's end for their managed challenge that has since been resolved by them. I've also made some tweaks thanks to the RayID you provided so that you're less likely to even encounter these in the future.
